# Populating a Matrix's nrow with a value from a calculated value

Tags: r, matrix, calculated-columns

I am running an R script to create a range based on a column (some of my code below). Is it possible to transalte my third column into the amount of rows in an empty matrix I have - that is not just the first value but create a matrix with the values in my third column. I have attached code I tried I using but it would only use the first value in my third column. I am not finished with my entire code but I am stumped. I am going to put some sample of what I am working towards if it helps clarifying the problem I am having and what I am aiming to do.

**sample data**

```
Data   Total
ID1 30980855
ID2 32874242       
ID3 25177144
```

**sample code that works and creates the Amount column**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){ 
Data$Amount = (round ((Data$Total/100000), digits = 0))
}
```

**sample output**

```
Data   Total   Amount
ID1 30980855            310
ID2 32874242            329
ID3 25177144            252
```

**my most recent attempt to populate nrows for an empty matrix**
everything I have tried so far only gives me a matrix that is 310 rows long but it does not move on to the next value below it like I expected it to

```
a = matrix(nrow=Data$Amount, ncol=3)
```

The reason I am attempting to make a matrix that has 310 rows followed by 329 rows etc... is because I have calculated those as the necessary window sizes to have 100k windows prior to reaching the maximum total. The final matrix will look something like this. With **start** being the initial position and **end** being the final position which will make up the 100k window/range.

```
Data   Start   End
ID1   1   100000
ID1   100001   200000
ID1   200001   300000
ID1   300001   400000
ID1   400001   500000
ID1   500001   600000
ID1   600001   700000
ID1   700001   800000
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve. The expected output you're showing has `Start` and `End` columns. Where do they come from? Can you provide an example with minimal data and *matching* expected output? Best to post an example with only a few rows and clearly detail the rules how to reproduce your expected output.

Comment: Yes. Sorry if my attempt was not clear. Let me fix it up.

Comment: Take 'ID1' for example. I caculated that there was '310' 100k windows. The `start` and `end` are what I am going to populate later. I am attempting to get `310` rows for `ID1` and `329` rows for `ID2` and so forth. I thought to show the expected output. I realized I mislabled my results as data. It should be fixed in a few.